# Returning the correct promise in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I'm having trouble returning the correct promise for a service in angular.

this is my function:

```
postToSP.post($scope.sharePointURL, data).then(function() {
            $scope.gettingData = false;
            $scope.yammerListName = "Successfully posted to SP"; 
        }).catch(function(e){
                        //console.log("Error: ", e);
                        $scope.yammerListName = "Sorry we couldn't post to that page, please make sure your column names are EXACTLY the same!"
                        $scope.gettingData = false;
                        throw e;
});
```

And this is my service, i get the error: "Unable to get property 'then' of undefined or null reference". I know it's because i'm not returning the promise properly but I can't figure out how to do it correctly. Please help, thanks in advance.

```
app.service("postToSP", function($http) {
        //Submit to SP function
        this.post = function(originalurl,data){

            console.log(data);

            var url = originalurl.split("Lists/")[0];
            var listname = originalurl.split("Lists/")[1].split("/")[0];

            //if the row is checked send it, if not jump to the next row

            //run the function, continue until the end and break
            var i = 0;
            return letsPost(i);

            function letsPost (i) { //i<data.length; i++

                if (data[i].checked == false) {
                      i++;
                      return letsPost(i);
                } else {

                    var formattedText = document.getElementById("text"+i).innerHTML.toString() ;
                    var formattedCreated = document.getElementById("created"+i).innerHTML.toString();
                    var formattedLikes = document.getElementById("likes"+i).innerHTML.toString();
                    var formattedLinks = document.getElementById("links"+i).innerHTML.toString();

                    var uploadData = { //change this for input data
                         '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.' + listname + 'ListItem' },
                        'Title': i + "",
                        'Likes': formattedLikes,
                        'Post_x0020_Date': formattedCreated,
                        'Post_x0020_Links' : formattedLinks,
                        'Post_x0020_Text': formattedText
                    };

                    console.log(uploadData);

                    createListItem(url, listname, uploadData)
                    .done(function (columnData) {
                        console.log('Added row' + i);
                        // if there is more data
                        if (i < data.length) {
                            i++;
                            return letsPost(i);
                            //add new data and continue the function
                        } else {
                            return;
                        }
                    })
                    .fail(function (error) {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
                        alert("Error:" + JSON.stringify(error));
                        throw error;
                    });

                    //Function to get form digest token
                    function getFormDigest(webUrl) {
                        return $.ajax({
                            url: webUrl + "/_api/contextinfo",
                            method: "POST",
                            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }
                        });
                    };

                    //Function to create the list item
                    function createListItem(webUrl, listName, itemProperties) {

                        $.ajax({
                            url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",
                            method: "GET",
                            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
                            success: function (data) {
                                console.log(data.d.results);
                            },
                            error: function (data) {
                                console.log(data);
                            }
                        });

                        return getFormDigest(webUrl).then(function (data) {

                            return $.ajax({
                                url: webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",
                                type: "POST",
                                processData: false,
                                contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                                data: JSON.stringify(itemProperties),
                                headers: {
                                    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                                    "X-RequestDigest": data.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    };
                };
            };
        };
});
```

Comment: Why you're using `$.ajax`? Why not using `$http`?

Comment: Your code looks really ugly, you should refactor it a bit. You need to make sure the `this.post` returns the promise.

Answer (score 0):

in your function declare the promise first

```
this.post = function(originalurl,data){
var deferred = $q.defer();
```

the data that you want to return use

```
deferred.resolve(dataToReturn)
```

and at the end of your function add

```
return deferred.promise;
```

Comment: This is an anti-pattern.

Comment: I don't think so, this pattern has been used in official docs

Comment: It's still an anti pattern; see why: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern

Comment: It's a way to look at it, yet it's not conclusive that it is anti pattern, might be one specific situation but not always. Nice information though thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand your code, mistake you are doing is you are returning the promise returned from `getFormDigest` but also applying `then` function on it and returning another promise. If you dont return `getFormDigest` nothing will be returned since its async.

To solve it you can use angular `$q` library and return and independent promise. Resolve that promise in your then function where you are returning a promise and no need to return `getFormDigest` so only one promise will be returned and hopefully your problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In simple way you can achieve it..i hope it make sense

```
//in your controller 
 yourService.addData(yourPayload);
    .then(function (cou) {
     $scope.data = cou.data;
 });

//in your service
this.addData = function (data) {      
    var response = $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: 'your url',
        data: data,
        dataType: "json"
    });
    return response;
}
```